# in express js while performing REST Api calls, in order to solve SQL queries and date, i need my sql methods

Tags: mysql, api, methods, backend

i just want to know mysql query methods while performing get, post, put, delete operations on server with database

i know SQlite commands but now i need to know mysql command. below is sqlite query.

```js
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(request.body.password, 10);
    const getUserQuery = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username="${username}"';
    const dbUser = await db.get(getUserQuery); --------this db.get method i need in MySql-------
    if (dbUser === undefined) {
        const createUserQuery = `
            INSERT INTO 
                user (username, name, password, gender, location)
            VALUES 
                (
                    '${username}',
                    '${name}',
                    '${hashedPassword}',
                    '${gender}',
                    '${location}'
                )`;
        const dbResponse = await db.run(createUserQuery);              
        const newUserId = dbResponse.lastID;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.